# Reading in a large text resource into arrays on iOS

Tags: ios

I have a large text resource in my bundle. It's a CSV containing lines like

```
0,1,100,2.2345
```

It's over 9MB. What's the best way to open and sequentially read it in so I can do something like:

```
myObject->initData(col0, col1, col2, col3);
```

(Which just stuffs the float value into one of a number of multidimensional arrays indexed by the integers in the file.)

I tried reading it into a string using `[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:]` and using an `NSScanner` to loop over it, but I don't want to double up my memory usage, even temporarily. It was also quite slow.

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NSFileHandle` or C APIs to read incrementally, or you can use mmap with `NSData`.

The remainder is basic cstring buffer handling, or you could use `NSString` line-by-line.

Your life may be easier if you can export it as a sequence of binary floats, rather than CSV.

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to use memory mapped data, so I'll try the NSFileHandle approach and read sequentially. Let me leave this open for a day or so to see if anyone else has other ideas (I mean, you've covered every base I can think of but you never know.)

Comment: C buffer handing (`fopen`, `fgets` etc.) worked in the end. Thanks.